# Make Dynamic referece to classes

Tags: android, javax.xml

I want to use javax libraries in android, but android does not allow them to use directly so i am using repackaged version. But the calling code is also in some other library which makes call to java.xml.stream.*. As repackaged version has the same class but with different package name , how can i invoke repackaged class.

I followed this tutorial , but it is too old and not working.

https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need javax classes?

Comment: @Emmanuel I am working on apache poi to create docx files which uses java.xml.stream.* classes internally